# Употребление множественного числа

Tags: множественное-число

Корректно ли использовать во множественном числе слова «инициатива» и «политика»? В сочетаниях вроде «предложенные инициативы», «политики компании» (имея в виду финансовую политику, политику в сфере управления персоналом и т. д.)?

Comment: Замысловатый вопрос. Особенно в свете некорректности словосочетаний "две инициативы, предложенных на встрече никакие, но остальные инициативы ничего", "три политики компании никакие, но оставшиеся политики ничего". Видимо со временем эта бодяга станет абсолютно корректной, а пока приграничная зона.